# Julia Parallel macro does not seem to work

Tags: parallel-processing, julia

I'm playing around for the first time with parallel computing with `julia`. I'm having a bit of a headache. So let's say I start `julia` as follows: `julia -p 4`. Then I declare the a function for all processors and then I use it with `pmap` and also with `@parallel for`.

```py
@everywhere function count_heads(n)
    c::Int = 0
    for i=1:n
        c += rand(Bool)
    end
    n, c  # tuple (input, output)
end

###### first part ######
v=pmap(count_heads, 50000:1000:70000)
println("Result first part")
println(v)

###### second part ######
println("Result second part")
@parallel for i in 50000:1000:70000
    println(count_heads(i))
end
```

The result is the following.

```
Result first part
Counting heads function
Any[(50000,24894),(51000,25559),(52000,26141),(53000,26546),(54000,27056),(55000,27426),(56000,28024),(57000,28380),(58000,29001),(59000,29398),(60000,30100),(61000,30608),(62000,31001),(63000,31520),(64000,32200),(65000,32357),(66000,33063),(67000,33674),(68000,34085),(69000,34627),(70000,34902)]
Result second part
    From worker 4:  (61000, From worker 5:  (66000, From worker 2:  (50000, From worker 3:  (56000
```

Thus, the funcion `pmap` is apparently working fine but `@parallel for` is stopping or it doesn't give me the results. Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks!

**Update**

If at the end of the code I put `sleep(10)`. It does the work correctly.

```
From worker 5:  (66000,33182)
From worker 3:  (56000,27955)
............
From worker 3:  (56000,27955)
```

Comment: Also: if you are trying to play around with these things its probably more useful, and maybe better practice, to assign things to an variable and then check what is returned (or use the fetched remote refs) rather than `println` as I guess thats more likely to be what you'll use them for later

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both of your examples work properly on my laptop so I'm not sure but I think this answer might solve your problem!

It should work as expected if you add `@sync` before the `@parallel for`

From the julia Parallel Computing Docs http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.4/manual/parallel-computing/:

> ... the reduction operator can be omitted if it is not
>   needed. In that case, the loop executes asynchronously, i.e. it spawns
>   independent tasks on all available workers and returns an array of
>   RemoteRef immediately without waiting for completion. The caller can
>   wait for the RemoteRef completions at a later point by calling fetch()
>   on them, or wait for completion at the end of the loop by prefixing it
>   with @sync, like @sync @parallel for.

So you are maybe calling `println` on the RemoteRef before it has completed.

Comment: Thanks! I replaced `@parallel` with  `@sync @parallel`. It works fine. Just as a general question. Why do you need that?

Comment: Do the docs not make sense? Without @sync the loop will return some objects (RemoteRef) immediately (i.e. even if the workers have not finished performing the function). To wait for them to complete before returning/printing an answer we can use `fetch()` or use @sync to wait at the end of the loop.