# Retrievieng SharedArray on Julia 0.4

Tags: arrays, parallel-processing, julia

Edit: I did try using `fetch()`

I seem to have break something in Julia this week. I had played with the SharedArray type on a computer with 12 threads (6 doble thread cpu), I maneged to get a result and to print it and save it as matrix text file without problem, more or less following the instructions on http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.4/manual/parallel-computing/#shared-arrays. I had this routine where I initialized a number of workers and an Array, pass them as argument to a function, and expected to obtain a SharedArray with numerical values in return. It went more or less like this

```
addprocs(11)
BCero=rand(128,128)
ConjuntoX=Array[]

for j,k=1:128
  push!(ConjuntoX, [j,k])
end


function obtenerKernelParalell(LasB::Array, lasX::Array, jmax::Int)
result=SharedArray(Float64,(jmax,jmax))
@sync @parallel for j=1:jmax
    xj=lasX[j]
     for k=1:j
        xk=lasX[k]
     for l=1:jmax
            xl=lasX[l]
            result[j,k]+= LasB[(xk-xl+xconstante)...]*LasB[(xj-xl+xconstante)...]
    end

    end
end 

end

KSuaveParalel=obtenerKernelParalell(BceroSuave, ConjuntoX,128);
```

What I did get after runing this for the first time was an array that behaved itself like a normal Array. If I typed `KSuaveParalel[3,12]` I obtained a value. But now I get the next thing from the REPL:
    KSuaveParalel

```
11-element Array{Any,1}:
RemoteRef{Channel{Any}}(2,1,122) 
RemoteRef{Channel{Any}}(3,1,123) 
RemoteRef{Channel{Any}}(4,1,124) 
RemoteRef{Channel{Any}}(5,1,125) 
RemoteRef{Channel{Any}}(6,1,126) 
RemoteRef{Channel{Any}}(7,1,127) 
RemoteRef{Channel{Any}}(8,1,128) 
RemoteRef{Channel{Any}}(9,1,129) 
RemoteRef{Channel{Any}}(10,1,130)
RemoteRef{Channel{Any}}(11,1,131)
RemoteRef{Channel{Any}}(12,1,132)
```

So I got an array of References... and I do not know how to get its values. Also using `fetch()` doesn't seem to work. 
What is going on here?

Comment: What does `fetch(KSuaveParalel[1])` return?

Comment: And you haven't returned the array in the function?

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:**

You need to make sure you return the array in the function. 
i.e. `return result`

---

You will want to call `fetch()` on each Remote Reference object to wait and get the value that will be returned.

`[fetch(x) for x in KSuaveParalel]`

The `RemoteRef` object is returned immediately (i.e. before the computation has actually been done). See this answer ([Julia Parallel macro does not seem to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39620354/julia-parallel-macro-does-not-seem-to-work/39621998#39621998)) and the docs for more info.

http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.4/stdlib/parallel/#Base.fetch

Comment: Sorry I did not get back to you sooner, here is the thing: `fetch(KSuaveParalel[1])` does not return anything! I even asigned it to a variable, and ask Julia to print it out: nothing at all....

Comment: And if I use the suggestion above I get this: `:
￼
[fetch(x) for x in KSuaveParalel]
Out[20]:
5-element Array{Any,1}:
 nothing
 nothing
 nothing
 nothing
 nothing `

Comment: because your function doesn't have a return statement!

Answer (score 0):

Okey, sort of figured a way to do it, but is not probably the most efficient way to do it: If I convert INSIDE the function the result from SharredArray to Array, I get the (apparently) correct result:

```
 function obtenerKernelParalell(LasB::Array, lasX::Array, jmax::Int)
     result=SharedArray(Float64,(jmax,jmax))
      @sync @parallel for j=1:jmax
        xj=lasX[j]
             for k=1:j
               xk=lasX[k]
               for l=1:jmax
                  xl=lasX[l]
                  result[j,k]+= LasB[(xk-xl+xconstante)...]*LasB[(xjxl+xconstante)...]
               end

     end
end 
 result=Array(result)
 return result
end
```

Is this because the conversion does the `fetch()` with the right settings automatically?